# Checking two conditions while iterating over an array of characters

Tags: c#

Having learned the basics/fundamentals of the C# programming language, I am now trying to tackle my first real-world problem: *Write a program that, given a string, finds its longest sub-string that contains **at least** one upper-case letter **but** no digits (and then displays the length of this longest sub-string).* This could be two **qualifying** conditions for an acceptable password, for example...

I have written the code below all by myself, which means there is probably performance issues, but that is for later consideration. I am stuck at the point where I have to make sure there is no digit in the sub-string. The comments in my code show my thinking while writing the program...

I thought first I should check to see if there is an upper-case letter in an extracted sub-string, and if there was, then I can store that qualifying sub-string in a list and then break out of the loop. But now I wonder how to check the no-digit condition at the same time in the same sub-string?

I am trying to keep it neat and simple (as I said I have only just started writing programs longer than a few lines!) so I thought doing a nested loop to check every character against `!char.IsNumber(letter)` might not be optimal. Or should I first check to see if there is no digit, then see if there is at least a capital character?

I feel confused how to achieve both restrictions, so I would appreciate some help in resolving this issue. I would also appreciate any **observations** or **suggestions** you might have. For example, is it OK to store my sub-strings in a list? Should I make a dictionary of some sort? Is my all-possible-sub-string extraction nested-loop optimal?

**p.s.** Some bits are still unfinished; for example I am still to implement the last step to find the longest sub-string and display to the user its length...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace PasswordRestriction
{
    class Program   /// Write a program that, given a string, finds the longest substring that is a valid password and returns its length.
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Ask the user for an alphanumeric string.
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a string of alphanumeric values:");

            // Receive the user input as string.
            string password = Console.ReadLine();

            // Print the length of the longest qualifying substring of the user string.
            Console.WriteLine("Length of the longest qualifying substring:\n" + Solution(password).Length );

            // Prevent the console window from closing.
            Console.ReadLine();
        }


        /// The method that exracts the longest substring that is a valid password.
        /// Note that a substring is a 'contiguous' segment of a string.
        public static string Solution(string str)
        {
            // Only allow non-empty strings.
            if ( String.IsNullOrEmpty(str) )
            {
                return "";
            }
            else
            {
                // Only allow letters and digits.
                if ( str.All(char.IsLetterOrDigit) )
                {
                    // A list for containing qualifying substrings.
                    List<string> passwordList = new List<string>();

                    // Generate all possible substrings. Note that
                    // string itself is not a substring of itself!
                    for (int i = 1; i < str.Length; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j <= (str.Length-i); j++)
                        {
                            string subStr = str.Substring(j, i);
                            Console.WriteLine(subStr);

                            bool containsNum = false;
                            bool containsUpper = false;

                            // Convert the substrings to arrays of characters with ToCharArray.
                            // This method is called on a string and returns a new character array.
                            // You can manipulate this array in-place, which you cannot do with a string.
                            char[] subStrArray = subStr.ToCharArray();

                            // Go through every character in each substring.
                            // If there is at least one uppercase letter and
                            // no digits, put the qualifying substring in a list.
                            for (int k = 0; k < subStrArray.Length; k++)
                            {
                                char letter = subStrArray[k];

                                if ( char.IsNumber(letter) )
                                {
                                    containsNum = true;
                                    break;
                                }

                                if ( char.IsUpper(letter) )
                                {
                                    containsUpper = true;
                                }

                                if ( containsUpper && (containsNum == false) && (k == subStrArray.Length - 1) )
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("Found the above legit password!");
                                    passwordList.Add(subStr);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    //Find the longest stored string in the list.
                    //if (passwordList.Count != 0)
                    //{
                        string maxLength = passwordList[0];

                        foreach (string s in passwordList)
                        {
                            if (s.Length > maxLength.Length)
                            {
                                maxLength = s;
                            }
                        }
                    //}

                    // Return the qualifying substring.
                    return maxLength;
                }
                else
                {
                    return "aaaaaaaaaa";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could take the index of all the numbers in the string, subtracting subsequent indices will give you the longest numeric-less string and then just search those for capital letters. You have at one point 3 for loops going and that will likely never be optimal.

Answer (score 3):

A good problem for *Linq*

- contains no digits - `Split` on digits
- at least one upper-case letter - `Where` + `Any`
- longest (not shortest) `OrderByDescending`
- longest (just one) - `FirstOrDefault`

Implementation

```
string source = ....

var result = source
  .Split('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9')
  .Where(line => line.Any(c => c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')) // or char.IsUpper(c)
  .OrderByDescending(line => line.Length)
  .FirstOrDefault(); // null if there're no such substrings at all
```

Comment: Similarily, with `Regex`, you could use `Split(@"\d")`, then `IsMatch("[A-Z]")`.

Comment: yeah but if the OP is not aware of the `Split` function let alone Linq how would one expect the OP to understand Regex regardless of how simple or complex the expression is..? just something to think about

Comment: @MethodMan: I see; but I think as well that the problem is a good one to demonstrate the power of Linq, how the complex problem can be solved in just four lines (and thus to encourage to invest some time to study Linq technique)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko the comment was not geared towards your answer it was geared towards `Scott Kaye` comment. your solution is spot on btw

Comment: Thank you all. The regex is above my head at the moment. I will explore the Split and Index methods, and see if I can complete my code. Will ask for further help and clarification as I go through these new areas...

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko: This is so elegant and succinct! Thanks. I will have to learn about Linq soon...

Comment: @Joshua: *Linq* is very convenient for many things (your problem included), IMHO it worth investing some time to study it

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the Linq answer, and if I understand you correctly, this is what I'd do, replacing the content of the str.All condition:

```
string qualifier;
string tempQualifier;
bool containsUpper = false;
for (int i = 0; i < str.Length(); i++) {
    tempQualifier += str[i];
    if (char.IsNumber(str[i])) {
        if (containsUpper) {
            if (tempQualifier.Length > qualifier.Length && tempQualifier.Length != str.Length) {
                qualifier = tempQualifier;
            }

            containsUpper = false;
        }

        tempQualifier = "";
    } else if (char.IsUpper(str[i])) {
        containsUpper = true;
    }
}

return qualifier;
```

This would go through the string, building up the substring until it comes across a number. If the substring contains an uppercase letter and is longer than any previous qualifier, it is stored as the new qualifier (also assuming that it isn't the length of the string provided). Apologies if I've made any mistakes (I'm not well versed in C#).

It's much longer than the Linq answer, but I thought it'd be handy for you to see the process broken down so you can understand it better.

Comment: Thank you! Based on your suggestion, I edited my code. Now, it seems to return the length of the longest sub-string (of the user input string) that has no digits and at least one uppercase letter. However, if you see towards the end please, where I find out the length of the longest sub-string, if my list is empty (i.e. no qualifying sub-string has been found and placed in the list) my program crashes of course, since `passwordList[0];` would be undefined. So, I tried to check for empty-ness using an if statement, but then the `mayLength` string would be out of scope (commented if)